# assign .setOnTouchListener() to layout defined in xml

Tags: android, layout, imageview, ontouchlistener

Im new to android so all Im trying to do is to program an application with few views interacting with user. My approach is to define layout with some imageviews in xml file and than programatically handle events on those imageviews.
However Im experiencing an issue with assigning .setOnTouchListener() to RelativeLayout previously defined in xml.

code looks like this:

```
public class ThreeActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    ImageView iv2;
    RelativeLayout rl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fish);

        ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
        iv1.setAlpha(50);


        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        iv2.setId(2);
        iv2.setOnTouchListener(this);

        iv2.setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (iv2.isFocused()) {
            TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
                    iv2.getLeft(), event.getX(), iv2.getTop(), event.getY());

            translateAnim.setDuration(1000);
            translateAnim
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            translateAnim.setFillAfter(true);

            iv2.setAnimation(translateAnim);

            iv2.startAnimation(translateAnim);
        }
        return true;
        }


}
```

obviously, I want an imageview to be focusable to recieve multiple events and than move it to touched position. And this is where Im  getting into trouble. RelativeLayout that Im touching just does not have touch listener set so I can't interact with it.

Can you help me with this or recommend another way to go?
Thank for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you read a little bit about the [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) class. Pay special attention to the `getAction()` method and all the action masks that this class provides you.

On your `onTouch()` method, you can do something like this:

```
if (v != iv2) return;
switch(ev.getAction()) {    
    case ACTION_DOWN: {
        // This block will run when the finger touches the screen
        mDoDrag = true;
        break;
    }    
    case ACTION_UP: {
        // This block will run when the finger leaves the screen
        mDoDrag = false;
        break;
    }    
    case ACTION_MOVE: {
        // This block will run when the finger is dragged across the screen
        if (mDoDrag) {
             // You should implement your animation here
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but none of this soulutinos is working :(
ImageView in solution no.2 is still listening just on square definied by that imageview iv2 itself and solution  no. 1 produces NullPointException!

Comment: You have to set the listener for all ImageViews. And on your onTouch() method, the v parameter is a reference to the view that was touched

Comment: I think you didn't get my question.
I want my object (imageview) to move anywhere where I tap. Of course if I would want to interact with all of imageviews, I would assign them onTouchListener and focus and than check on particular view in onTouch method if it was touched an where it should move.

thing is that I can't tell them where to move cause RelativeLayout in this example has no onTouchListener assigned, so I can't get coordinates.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you wanted to drag your ImageView. Then all you have to do is assign a listener to your RelativeLayout and then on the onTouch() of said listener you'll have the coordinates to move your ImageView to.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThreeActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    ImageView iv2;
    RelativeLayout rl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fish);

        ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
        iv1.setAlpha(50);


        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        iv2.setId(2);
        r1.setOnTouchListener(this);

        iv2.setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (v == iv2) {
            TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
                    iv2.getLeft(), event.getX(), iv2.getTop(), event.getY());

            translateAnim.setDuration(1000);
            translateAnim
                    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            translateAnim.setFillAfter(true);

            iv2.setAnimation(translateAnim);

            iv2.startAnimation(translateAnim);
        }
        return true;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

if setOnTouchListener doesn't work for your layout, you can extend it and handle [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)